# Can I Select Through A Face When Using Subsurface Modifier?

Tags: modeling, modifiers, edit-mode

I am using cubes with a Catmull-Clark subsurface modifier for blocking out a model. I am having difficulty with areas where different cubs intersect. I need to be able to select edges and vertices that are within another cube, but are visible due to the subsurface modifier.

An example is shown below...

[image]

The green edge is what I want to select, but it is inside the shape marked in red.

Sometimes I am able to select edges and vertices that are inside another shape, but still visible due to the modifier. I can't figure out what allows me to do so in those circumstances.

I could move the shapes out of the way, make the adjustment, then move it back into place, but this seems cumbersome.

Comment: Did you try wireframe mode? shift + Z

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to hide (H) the vertex, edged or faces you don't want to select.